# display selected option in its next td of html table

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function a()
 {
 var e2 = document.getElementById("fid");
 var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
 document.getElementById("fid2").value=strUser2;

 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>A</th>
  <th>B</th>
  <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="id1" form="form2" id="id1" class="form-control input-sm" ></td>
      <td><select class="form-control" id="fid" name="fid" form="form2" required>
        <option value="" selected>Select</option>
        <c:forEach var="b"  items="${model.list2}">
        <option value="${b.id}">${b.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
         </select></td>
         
          <td ><input class="form-control" id="fid2" name="fid2" required></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Table rows are dynamic. Rows will populate based on the search made. Only second and third column are editable.Column 3 should contain a value which has been selected in column 2. This code is working only for the 1st row. But it should work for all the row. How to achieve it.

Comment: two elements can never have same Id

Comment: you are using same id for multiple element, try changing it

Comment: Actually these table rows are dyamic. I have edited my snippet so please do check once and let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way because no two elements on a single webpage can have same id. You can also do this using class selectors.

```js
function a()
 {
 var e1 = document.getElementById("id1");
 var strUser2 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
 document.getElementById("id2").value=strUser2;

 }
 function b()
 {
 var e2 = document.getElementById("id3");
 var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
 document.getElementById("id4").value=strUser2;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>A</th>
  <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><select class="form-control select" id="id1" name="id1" onchange="a()" required>
       <option selected>Select</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
        <option>F</option>
        </select></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="id2" id="id2" class="texts"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><select class="form-control" id="id3" name="id3" onchange="b()" required>
       <option selected>Select</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
        <option>F</option>
        </select></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="id4" id="id4"></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the select to your function, to prevent one DOM query, and match the select to the input with the property name to id.

This way its cleaner, faster and reusable.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ya0upf7a/)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select class="form-control" name="id1" onchange="a( this )" required>
      <option selected>Select</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
      <option>F</option>
      </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select class="form-control" name="id2" onchange="a( this )" required>
      <option selected>Select</option>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
      <option>E</option>
      <option>F</option>
      </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
  function a( select ) {
    var target = document.getElementById( select.name );
    target.value = select.value;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on Ids, I would solve it this way
function a now takes 2 arguments, first is the current select element,
the second is the id of the input to update ( it should be different and not duplicated )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="id1" name="id1" onchange="a(this, 'id2')" required>
             <option selected>Select</option>
              <option>A</option>
              <option>B</option>
              <option>C</option>
              <option>D</option>
              <option>E</option>
              <option>F</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id2" id="id2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select class="form-control " id="id1" name="id1" onchange="a(this, 'id3')" required>
             <option selected>Select</option>
              <option>A</option>
              <option>B</option>
              <option>C</option>
              <option>D</option>
              <option>E</option>
              <option>F</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id3" id="id3"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script>
        function a(select, inputId) {
            var input = document.getElementById(inputId)
            input.value = select.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```